# Call a function from a button that is created during jqGrid's gridComplete event?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to call a function in the onclick event of the button that is created during the gridComplete event..Loads OK…here's what the rendered html looks like for the button in the first row

```
<input type="button" onclick="deleteRow(9197113);" value="Delete" style="height: 22px; width: 70px;">
```

but when i click the button…the function is not called and firebug says….

deleteRow is not defined

How can I call a function, rather than having inline javascript,,,(which does work BTW, but I  would like to call the function for readability and maintainability). I've included the working inline javascript...it's commented out in the below snippet...

Below is the grid Complete portion of the jqGrid settings.

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({

   ........................

    gridComplete: function() {
        var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            var cl = ids[i];
            de = "<input style='height:22px;width:70px;' type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow('" + cl + "' );' />";   
            //de = "<input style='height:22px;width:70px;' type='button' value='Delete' onclick=\"jQuery('#list').jqGrid('delGridRow', '" + cl + "', {msg: 'Delete this entry?'});\" />"; 
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { Delete: de });
        }
    }

   ........................

 });
```

Here's the deleteRow() function…

```
function deleteRow() {
    alert("hit delete button");
    // jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('delGridRow', row_id_s,options );
}
```

Comment: Where is `deleteRow` defined? It sounds like you're not calling it in the right scope.

Comment: It's in the same javascript file...right below the jqGrid setup stuff

Comment: When you say right below, is it a direct child of your ready function? Is it just a direct child of a `<script>` block? Is it in a JavaScript object?

Comment: It's literally right below the jqGrid setup stuff...the jqGrid setup stuff ends, there's a blank line, and the very next line is the deleteRow function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change your grid complete function so that it gives the imput a class of say "delete" and then in my document ready function setup a live click event for that class selector.

something like this

```
gridComplete: function() {
    var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        var cl = ids[i];
        de = '<input style="height:22px;width:70px;" type="button" class="delete" value="Delete" />';
        $("#list").jqGrid('setRowData', ids[i], { Delete: de });
    }
}

$('#list .delete').live('click',function(){
    var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
});
```

Comment: I'll try your suggestion...just have to determine how to feed it the row id...as jqGrid's delGridRow method needs the row id
    jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('delGridRow', row_id_s,options );

Comment: Awesome!!! the live click event worked...never used it before but it's nice to be able to add it to my bag of tricks!

Answer (score 1):

You could define `deleteRow` as a custom jQuery function, and then call it on selected elements.

```
$.fn.deleteRow = function() { 
    row_id = $(this).attr('id');
    return $("#grid_id").jqGrid('delGridRow', row_id);
}
```

Call it like this:

```
$("#grid_id button[value=Delete]").click( function() {
    $(this).parents('.row_class').deleteRow();
});
```

I'd imagine that would need to be more complex--I'm not familiar with jqGrid, but what you need to do is pretty straightforward.

---

Could you post some markup? It's difficult to tell how to select the row by ID without seeing it.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion...just have to determine how to feed it the row id...as jqGrid's delGridRow method needs the row id
    jQuery("#grid_id").jqGrid('delGridRow', row_id_s,options );

Comment: Alright, you'll want to change `return $(this).doWhatsNeededHere;` as I did above, making adjustments to fit your needs.