# jqgrid custom edit function undefined

Tags: jquery, function, jqgrid

Ive just started playing with jqgrid and am experiencing a strange problem?

ive copied the custom edit example from the jqgrid demo's site and have added an extra button

my code:

```
gridComplete: function(){ 
            var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
            for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){ var cl = ids[i]; 
                be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').editRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />";
                gc = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='G' onclick=\"geocodeMe("+cl+");\" />";
                jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{Actions:be+se+ce+gc}); 
            } 
        }
```

when i click the button labeled G it should i thoughr call my function

but i get a js error that geocodeMe is undefined
its in my code so dont know why it cant find it am guessing its a scope problem, any ideas how to fix it???

the geocodeMe function:

```
function geocodeMe(myID) {
        // set default region
        region = 'uk';
        // address not empty
        removemarkers();
        $('#geo_detail').html('<label>Geocoding address...</label>');
        // lookup the address
        var myData = $("#rowed2").getRowData(myID);
        address = myData.geoaddr_mdt;
        geocoder.geocode( {'address':address,'region':region}, function(results, status) {
            // if the address was found
            if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $str = '<label>Geocode Successful<br> Lattitude: '+results[0].geometry.location.lat()+' Longitude: '+results[0].geometry.location.lng()+'<br> The address is displayed below and will be stored in the database.<br> If the address is incorrect you may edit it before saving the location to the database.<br>If the marker is in the wrong location you may drag it to where you  believe it should be.</label>';
                $('#geo_detail').html($str);
                // insert lat/long into form
                $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                // create new lat/long object
                latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(),results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                $('#disp_addr').val(address);
                $('#form_buttons').show();
                $('#detail_address').show();
                //reverselookup(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                // set zoom option
                map.setZoom(15);
                // center the map on the new location
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                createMarker(map, latlng, true, false);

                if(savetype ='update'){
                    savedata('update');
                };
                if(savedata='save'){
                    savedata('save');
                };
            } else {
                // display error
                $('#geo_detail').append('<label>Geocoder failed to retrieve address: '+status+'</label>');
                $('#disp_addr').val($('#geo_addr').val());
            };
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

found the answer in this thread [Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774018/call-a-function-from-a-button-that-is-created-during-jqgrids-gridcomplete-event)

i craeted a class for the button called geocode me,

```
gridComplete: function(){ 
            var ids = jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('getDataIDs'); 
            for(var i=0;i < ids.length;i++){ var cl = ids[i]; 
                be = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='E' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').editRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                se = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='S' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').saveRow('"+cl+"');\" />"; 
                ce = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='C' onclick=\"jQuery('#rowed2').restoreRow('"+cl+"');\" />";
                gc = "<input style='height:22px;width:20px;' type='button' value='G' class='geocodeMe' rel='"+cl+"' />";
                jQuery("#rowed2").jqGrid('setRowData',ids[i],{Actions:be+se+ce+gc}); 
            }
```

then created a click function for that class which reads in the rel attribute holding the correct id:

```
$('body').delegate('.geocodeMe', 'click', function() {
        var myID = $(this).attr('rel');
        var myData = $("#rowed2").getRowData(myID);
        rest of function code.............

    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer which is really helpful. @Dizzy Bryan High

Answer (score 1):

If you use `onclick=\"geocodeMe("+cl+")`, the function `geocodeMe` must be defined as **global**, so on the top level like `jQuery`.

I recommend you to look other possibilities to implement the same behaviors: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303471/browser-memory-usage-comparison-inline-onclick-vs-using-jquery-bind/5305904#5305904) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5196387/jqgrid-editactioniconscolumn-events/5204793#5204793).

Moreover you should be clear that enumeration through all items of `jqGrid('getDataIDs')` in for loop could be very slow in case of large number of items in the grid (about 100 or more). Much more effective way is to use jQuery selection described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010761/linking-from-a-column-value-in-jqgrid-to-a-new-page-using-get/5017528#5017528). Even more effective way is the usage of `rows` array of the `table` element and `cells` property inside of any `rows` element. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008115/jqgrid-calculate-total-column-cells-amount-depending-on-other-column-cell-values/6008705#6008705) one more answer which also includes corresponding demo.